# EWS : How throttling will be affected when migrating to Modern Authentication ( Oauth 2.0) from Basic Authentication

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, microsoft-teams

We have been using EWS API using Basic Authentication to access Teams data. As Microsoft is decommissioning Basic Authentication and recommend to use Modern Authentication (Oauth 2.0), we have been working on this. 
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/basic-authentication-and-exchange-online-april-2020-update/ba-p/1275508

In EWS API, there is throttling on API calls so I tried to find MS Documentation on how throttling will be affected while switching from basic auth to modern auth.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/ews-throttling-in-exchange

In Basic Auth, we need to pass user name and password of application impersonation account and MS imposes throttling per this account. And it allows maximum of 27 concurrent calls per impersonation account. 
I tried to search any documentation related to this but could not find it so far.

The reason I am asking this is because we have been utilizing multiple application impersonation accounts to increase our concurrency there by increasing our throughput. Now, when we switch to Oauth, we will lose this capability so looking any way to enhance our application performance while switching.
Ref: see pool of account in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/webdav_101/ews-serverbusyexception-the-server-is-too-busy-for-you
Any insights would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you please use [Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/teams-api-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0) to get data for Microsoft Teams? Also could you please go through Throttling docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/throttling)

Comment: Thanks @Nikitha-MSFT for suggesting this. We were also looking this option but it seems  there are still couple of limitations which prevent us to switch to graph.
1. We need to capture both Teams conversations and Direct Message (1:1 and 1:many group conversations). For teams, there is Application permission but for Direct Message, it just supports delegated permission.
2. The API still seems in beta.
3. It does not support capturing edited messaged.

Comment: 4. We have big clients with millions of message produced daily so based on the link you provided, it looks like we will be heavily throttled.